# Django - changing ID field

Tags: django, django-views

So I understand it's not good practice to use the keyword - ID. So, I tried changing the id below to cid. However, when I do this I get: testing() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'. If I change it back from cid to ID. Everything works just fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
def testing(request, cid):
    """Testing sheet for controls"""
    if request.method == "GET":
        testing_sheet = IsoControls.objects.get(pk=cid)
        form = forms.ControlTesting(instance=testing_sheet)
        return render(request, 'controls_app/testing_sheet.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        testing_sheet = IsoControls.objects.get(pk=cid)
        form = forms.ControlTesting(request.POST, instance=testing_sheet)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return render(request, 'controls_app/testing_sheet.html', {'form':form})
```

Updating based on comments.

My URL is

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'), 
    path('<int:id>', views.testing, name='testing') 
]
```

In my html

```
<td>
    <a href="{% url 'testing' control.id %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
</td>
```

Comment: Where is `testing` being called? It's being called with `id=something` - that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
def testing(request, pk):
    """Testing sheet for controls"""

    testing_sheet = IsoControls.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = forms.ControlTesting(instance=testing_sheet)
    if request.method=='POST':
       form = forms.ControlTesting(request.POST, instance=testing_sheet)          

           if form.is_valid():
              form.save()
              return redirect('../your_given_path_name')

    return render(request, 'controls_app/testing_sheet.html', {'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok - so this was a silly mistake. I changed it CID in my views but i also needed to change the URL partern to CID.

URL:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'), 
    path('<int:cid>', views.testing, name='testing') 
]
```

Views

```
def testing(request, cid):
    """Testing sheet for controls"""
    if request.method == "GET":
        testing_sheet = IsoControls.objects.get(pk=cid)
        form = forms.ControlTesting(instance=testing_sheet)
        return render(request, 'controls_app/testing_sheet.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        testing_sheet = IsoControls.objects.get(pk=cid)
        form = forms.ControlTesting(request.POST, instance=testing_sheet)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return render(request, 'controls_app/testing_sheet.html', {'form':form})
```